# How do I get a Resource ID edit in MFC editor to propagate to code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I make a button in the resource editor in an MFC program.
I give it an ID.
I use the ID in code with `CWnd *tLabel = GetDlgItem(IDC_CHANGETWO);`
I am pleased.

I go back to editor
I change the ID
Code does not acknowledge new name, even with rebuild
I change some flag (tabstop)
Code still does not care

In order to get an ID name change to propagate to the code, I have to change the ID AND any other field in the same save.  Only then does it realize it is dirty and update the resource table.

This is 100% reproducible on mine and my students' computers.  This workaround has kept the class from stalling, but... what the heck is this?

Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL

Comment: What do you mean by `to get an ID name change to propagate to the code`? Propagate WHERE? The studio will never change your C++ code to update the ID of the control. Should it?

Comment: It's really hard to follow what you're asking here.

Comment: @CBGraham Did my answer help you?

Comment: Oh, all the newlines got stripped.  Looked much better before.  Short version: If I change an ID in the resource editor, cpp files can't see it.  I need to change the ID and any other flag to get the resource file to notice it is dirty, even with rebuild.

Comment: I have the same issue in Visual Studio 2019. I got an error: `E0020 identifier "IDC_CHANGETWO" is undefined`. Build Solution, Rebuild Solution, Clean Solution did not clear this error. But, if I reopen the solution, the error is gone. The trick helps me, but I don't know why. Hope someone can help to explain it.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the name of a resource control it will not propagate that throughout your source code as you have already learned.

Ideally you need to use something like **VisualAssist**: http://www.wholetomato.com/

It allows you to rename your resource ID values

What you need to use is **refactoring**. If you open your resource file as a text file in the IDE (as opposed to the resource editor) and locate your control, you should be able to right-click it and choose **Refactor (VA)**:

[image: Renaming a resource ID]

Then select **Rename**. It should preview the changes in the various source code files:

[image: Refactor preview]

You can use the same procedure for renaming variables and method declarations.

Comment: I don't have the ability to get Visual Assist on the computers, but your Refactoring point makes total sense.  A variable name change in C++ doesn't propagate without Refactor of course.  I was viewing the Resource editor as being more automated than a cpp file.  (This works in Window Builder in Eclipse-Java.)  But like I keep telling the class, C++ hates you and doesn't do anything automatically.  Imma try to find Refactor for an ID without Visual Assist and come back in a bit.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b4ffb8a.aspx
Microsoft sez the right way to change the name is to type it in the box like I'm doing.  But if I don't also change another flag at the same time, the symbol won't work in the actual code still.  100%.
I never wanted to teach C++.  I wanted to be a lumberjack.

Comment: @CBGraham what about this: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/164904b2-3b47-417f-9b6b-fdd35757d194

Comment: Renamed 'IDC_MIDDLEC2' to 'IDC_MIDDLED':
----------------------------------------
Error occured while applying changes, partial changes may exist.

Comment: Rename doesn't work on Resource IDs apparently.  How is this not a thing with y'all?  If I make a label, the very first thing I want to do is change the label from IDC_STATIC to well, anything else.

Comment: It is not a issue for me because i use Visual Assist you see.

Comment: Well, poop.  I'll suggest Visual Assist be put on the computers in the Fall.  That makes "use Visual Assist" the correct answer so I'll mark this done.  I'll feel bad for the next person though that the official answer is that Visual Studio hates happiness.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the other answer made me realize this wouldn't work so I had to un-check this.  The name of the ID I'm changing away from is IDC_STATIC.  Even Visual Assist couldn't resist changing every static in the app at that point.

Comment: @CBGraham Well yes, labels are named ICD_STATIC automatically so if you want them personalized you will have no choice than to do it some other way. Your original question did not state IDC_STATIC. It is a special case. My answer is for the question stated you see. Else I would have explained this to you. I do now realise your comments where you said IDC_STATIC. But it is best to rename them at design time, before adding your variables and handlers. Prevention is better than cure. Add static control, rename directly in the properties. Then add variable etc..

Comment: I added a second answer for IDC_STATIC. Not sure what the issue is with that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer given is good, it doesn't show what happens behind the scene when you update a resource ID.

- All resource IDs go into one header: **resource.h**
- This file is read by C++ compiler, as well as by resource compiler (the `.RC` file.)
- Using resource editor, you just type an ID, and the resource-editor would simply create an entry in **resource.h**

This header looks like:

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by MFCApplication1.rc
//
#define IDR_MAINFRAME                   128
#define IDM_ABOUTBOX                    0x0010
#define IDD_ABOUTBOX                    100
#define IDS_ABOUTBOX                    101
#define IDD_MFCAPPLICATION1_DIALOG              102

// Next default values for new objects
//
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE    129
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE     1000
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE       101
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE     32771
#endif
#endif
```

So, when you add a new control on dialog (or any other form), and name it `IDC_DOWNLOAD_NOW`, and save the resource, this header will get updated like:

```
#define IDR_MAINFRAME                   128
#define IDC_DOWNLOAD_NOW                1000
```

Also, internal variable (like `_APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE` gets updated).

Well.. when you have same symbol in **other dialog**, VS will simply use the same macro with same value. You add another button on third dialog with same name, it doesn't modify `resource.h` either.

But... when you modify control in these 3 dialogs to name is like `IDC_DOWNLOAD_LATER`, only `.RC` and `resource.h` get updated. Old value, and old usages still exist. You wont get any compiler error (since macros are there!).

```
#define IDR_MAINFRAME                   128
#define IDC_DOWNLOAD_NOW                1000
#define IDC_DOWNLOAD_LATER              1001
```

In another case, when you remove the button (from any of 3 dialog boxes), program will compile fine, but `GetDlgItem`, `DDX_Control` etc will fail at runtime (Since `IDC_DOWNLOAD_NOW` doesn't exist in current dialog!)

Now think what would happen if you **mass rename** the symbols using any tool - **boom** - all resources now have `IDC_DOWNLOAD_LATER`!

You should use **Resource Symbols** dialog to find what resource IDs are used by which dialog. From here you can rename and delete also.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a great answer for a different question.  My problem is that resource.h isn't actually getting updated if I change an ID in the property panel without touching another flag at the same time.  Place text, change IDC_Static to IDC_DoSomething, code can't see it.  Change TabStop or something at the same time, code gets the update.

Comment: You need to save the currently edited resource, it's then only `resource.h` will get updated. Note that tabstop, and other properties of control aren't part of `resource.h` but `.RC` file. The reason is simple - `resource.h` is used by C++ compiler also. `.RC` file is not read (and isn't needed) by C++ compiler. Try to get whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a second possible way to handle the specific issue of **IDC_STATIC**. Your question should be modified to include this.

I have started a temporary dialogue project and selected the default static text:

[image: Default static text]

As you can see, it is labelled **IDC_STATIC**. I now directly change the ID value in the resource editor itself and hit the *enter* key:

[image: Rename property]

Then I **save** it (this updates the resource.h file). Then, this is what we see if I use an application called **ResOrg**:

[image: Using ResOrg]

As you can see, the resource.h file is correct. It is at this point you now add your variables.

Interestingly, the IDE does not actually allow you to add variables to IDC_STATIC objects anyway. But suppose you have two if them:

[image: 2 Static objects]

You can still rename each one, save the file, re-build, and view your resource file:

[image: Rename 2 other static controls]

As you can see, it is all still good. It is at this point that you can add variables and event handlers now. And it is in this context where VisualAssist would be used to rename variables/ID's used throughout your application.

I was not sure to edit my existing answer with this additional information. Perhaps that might be better?